# get pte of page in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, paging

I'm trying to write code that gets a page and returns it PTE (page table entry) in the Linux kernel.

The prototype of the function should be something like this:

```
static pte_t getPteOfPage(struct page *page);
```

I tried to find the PTE of the page in the struct description of the page, but it is more complicated.

Can anyone show how to do it?

Comment: Check the try_to_unmap(). You may know that one page can be mapped in different process space, so on page could have many ptes.

Answer (score 1):

Good starting point to look at the `walk_page_range` function.

```
/**
 143 * walk_page_range - walk a memory map's page tables with a callback
 144 * @addr: starting address
 145 * @end: ending address
 146 * @walk: set of callbacks to invoke for each level of the tree
 147 *
 148 * Recursively walk the page table for the memory area in a VMA,
 149 * calling supplied callbacks. Callbacks are called in-order (first
 150 * PGD, first PUD, first PMD, first PTE, second PTE... second PMD,
 151 * etc.). If lower-level callbacks are omitted, walking depth is reduced.
 152 *
 153 * Each callback receives an entry pointer and the start and end of the
 154 * associated range, and a copy of the original mm_walk for access to
 155 * the ->private or ->mm fields.
 156 *
 157 * Usually no locks are taken, but splitting transparent huge page may
 158 * take page table lock. And the bottom level iterator will map PTE
 159 * directories from highmem if necessary.
 160 *
 161 * If any callback returns a non-zero value, the walk is aborted and
 162 * the return value is propagated back to the caller. Otherwise 0 is returned.
 163 *
 164 * walk->mm->mmap_sem must be held for at least read if walk->hugetlb_entry
 165 * is !NULL.
 166 */
```

See the [walk_page_range](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.11/mm/pagewalk.c#L142) function implementation, for a good example.

Comment: I saw that the function `pte_page()` returns the `pte_t` of page, but it is not the case on x86. Is there another function that does it?